# What’s going on with the Grimm and Tyrian?

Tags: rwby

In *RWBY* Season 4, Episode 11, Tyrian

> confesses his failure to Salem.

After doing so, she expresses her disappointment. A huge Grimm then enters the room and leaps for Tyrian’s exposed back, but Tyrian turns around and starts slicing at it while crying (in fear?), but it doesn’t appear to die.

What’s going on here? My initial impression is that Salem felt Tyrian had outlived his usefulness, and basically was telling him that he had to die at the hands of the Grimm. But why would she let him fight back, if that were the case? In any case, the Grimm didn’t seem to be much of a threat. Was having to fight the Grimm some sort of punishment?  Or was it simply a leftover Grimm from Cinder’s fight?

Comment: Are we doing [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8006/31394) again with aSoIaF characters now? :-)

Comment: @Randal’Thor - No, that’s just his name (well, maybe it’s spelled some weird way, I don’t know). I couldn’t make it terribly descriptive.

Comment: @Randal’Thor - Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It is indeed a leftover.

Cinder goes against four Grimm.

[image: Cinder VS 4 Grimm]

She slices two of them in one go.

[image: Cinder kills two Grimm]

She fire-punches a third one.

[image: Cinder kills a third Grimm]

After what she falls to her knees and Salem enters the room, saying "Enough". So, there's a fourth Grimm waiting in a corner like a good ol' doggo. I figure Salem controls the Grimm, or if she doesn't well they're not stupid enough to go against her.

Long story short, Tyrian comes in and announces his failure, Salem is disappointed and leaves him as is. For the devoted fanboy Tyrian is, that must indulge *a lot* of bad emotions. Grimm are attracted by negativity, so I reckon the fourth one wanted to take a chew. Didn't work out well for him. I don't think Salem even remembered the Grimm.

---

As to why the Grimm didn't die right away, I can see two reasons:

- the more Tyrian beats him, the more negative he feels, fueling the Grimm. It's debatable, though;
- Rooster Teeth wanted to show what a psycho he is. Hey, even *Cinder* seems to be shocked by the raw violence and madness, and she's pretty vicious herself.

---

The character's name is indeed spelled "Tyrian" with an a, not like the *A Song of Ice and Fire* character, as proven by the credits:

[image: end credits with correct spelling of Tyrian's name]